# Content not being added to UIPopoverController?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting, uipopovercontroller

I'm new to iOS development so please cut me some slack.
I'm trying to learn how to use UIPopoverCotroller and I'm having a problem.
The popover appears correctly but nothing is added to it, its just black.
I'm using this line of code to  try to add content to the popover:

```
self.photosPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:self.photosPopoverViewController];
```

Heres some more code to help:

```
-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{
    self.photosPopover=nil;
}

-(IBAction)photosPopoverButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    if([self.photosPopover isPopoverVisible]){
        [self.photosPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.photosPopover=nil;
        return;
    }

    self.photosPopoverViewController = [[PhotosPopoverViewController alloc]init];
    self.photosPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:self.photosPopoverViewController];
    [self.photosPopover setDelegate:self];
    [self.photosPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [self.photosPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
}
```

I'm using Xcode 4.3, ARC, and storyboards.

Thanks for your help!

-Shredder2794

Comment: If you NSLog self.photosPopoverViewController right after you init it does it give you an object?

Comment: Is viewDidLoad or anything like that getting called in your viewController?

Comment: Yes, ViewDidLoad is being called

Comment: Have you tried presenting the view outside of a Popover to ensure the popover is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I just tried and when i do a Modal segue to that view it works fine

Comment: I've just created a test project with your exact code and it worked fine. I'm not sure exactly whats wrong but I need more code to find out. Either you're clearing the contentViewController somewhere else or your PhotosPopoverViewController has an error in it.

Comment: You did read that I'm using ARC and storyboards right?

Comment: Could you send your test project to me via email?

Comment: I used both ARC and storyboards in my demo

Comment: Could you send your project tome via email

Comment: http://cl.ly/GkyB Here is my test project. Its very simple, very dirty, but I used your exact code and created a Photos view controller and set it background to orange to verify.

Comment: I've got to go but I'll check this thread again tomorrow.

Comment: ok thanks ill look it over. thanks SO mcuh for all your help! :)

Comment: Ok I found out what the problem was but still need help. I was linking my the class for the popover to a UIViewController object using storyboards. For some reason it doesn't display the UIViewController that I build with storyboard but when I build the interface via code in the classes file it all works fine. How can I get it to link up with a UIViewController that I made using storyboards(if that's how you say it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your view from storyboards. Sorry I didn't see this sooner...

```
self.photosPopoverViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"photosViewController"];
```

[image]

This is how you connect a customViewController to a viewController object in Storyboards. You build your PhotosPopoverViewController.h and PhotosPopoverViewController.m then you click your viewController object in storyboards and find the Custom Class identifier. Start typing your class name and it will autofill it.

[image: This is how you connect a customViewController to a viewController object in Storyboards.]

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload your project somewhere on the web so I could just have a look?

Comment: I would preferr not too. Why would the UIViewController in a storyboard not link up with its class? I found how to make the popover work correctly but it only works if I build the interface via code not its UIViewContoller in the main sotoryboard. By the way the UIViewController object in the main storyboard IS linked up with its class via teh identity inspector but it doesent appear in the popover. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you overriding the init or anything like that? Could we post some of the code for the view lifecycle of the controller?

Comment: Heres all the code from the implementation file from the class that is put in the popover: `
    #import "PhotosPopoverViewController.h"

@implementation PhotosPopoverViewController

@synthesize mainLabel = _mainLabel;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.mainLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    self.mainLabel.text=@"hi";
    [self.view addSubview:self.mainLabel];
}

@end`

Comment: "Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more…"

Comment: Well then I stand corrected. The code looks fine. I can't see any reason it wouldn't work. I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: You aren't overriding `- (void)loadView` at all are you?

Comment: I noticed that in the project you put up on dropbox that you build the UI via code also. Could you modify the project to incorporate a UI in the popover build in the main storyboard?

Comment: http://cl.ly/Gnd6 Also here is the updated sample project with the code and storyboard versions. I commented out the storyboard code so you can click both buttons and see one will show both labels the other will show only the code label. if you uncomment the code you'll see the same on both buttons.

Comment: Glad we finally found an answer for you :) Happy Coding.